# WCF Service calling an external web service results in timeouts in heavy load environment

Tags: wcf

I have got the following scneario:

Our .NET client calls our WCF service - which in turn calls an external third party service to retrieve some data. Once the data is retrieved, our WCF service sets some values and then returns the control back to the client.  The process of calling the external service has to be synchronous.

My problem is that this all works in a low load environment but when load gets high then we start queueing multiple requests, the WCF service starts timing out.  We have set the "sendTimeout" property for the binding to 5 seconds and it times out after that.

I've tried replacing the external service with a mocked out local version and that handles the load OK but on the same hand the call to external service on it own is very quick - around 0.5 second.  I can only presume that the timeouts are happening because too many requests were queued and WCF service couldn't respond within those allocated 5 seconds.

I have tried the following:

- Set the values of maxConcurrentCalls, maxConcurrentSessions & maxConcurrentInstances to very high numbers
- Set the value of system.net - connectionManagement - maxconnection to a very high number

Does any one have any ideas about what we can do in this scneario?

Comment: Any chance that your heavy load condition is also heavy load for the external service?  Did you try calling the external service directly at the same load level?

Comment: I was going to try that out.  Will do that next when I get back to office on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

does your cpu peak during these high load times ? if not then you might be running out of threads. Make your wcf service that receives the original call asynchronous, and then call the external service asynchronously.

you will have to use asnyc pattern throughout your call chain to make sure nothing is blocking the thread.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177.aspx

Comment: The CPU usage does actually peak a lot around the high load times.  I'm using the Visual Studio Load Testing tools to replicate this.  I have also tried experimenting with the ContextMode and ConcurrencyMode properties but that didn't help either.

Comment: if the cpu is peaking, then you have hit a hardware threshold, you could use the visual studio profiler (or some other ones) to see which part of your code is taking most time