# WCF client timeout under heavy load

Tags: wcf

I have already asked a similar question here: [WCF Service calling an external web service results in timeouts in heavy load environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689841/wcf-service-calling-an-external-web-service-results-in-timeouts-in-heavy-load-env) but I've got a better idea now as to what's happening so posting a new question.

This is what is happening:

- .NET client sends multiple requests at the same time to a WCF service (if it helps - I'm replicating this scneario by using Visual Studio Load Tests)
- The client has got a "sendTimeout" set to 5 seconds
- The WCF service receives it and start processing it.  The processing involves sending a request to an external service which could take about 1 second to come back with a response
- This is where I think the problem is: the client has sent many requests to the service and since the service is still busy processing the concurrent requests, some of the reqeusts from the client are timing out after 5 seconds

I have tried the following:

- Changed the InstanceContextMode to PerCall
- Increased the values of maxConcurrentCalls & maxConcurrentInstances
- Increased the value of connectionManagement.maxconnection in machine.config

But none of that seems to be making any difference.  Does anyone has any idea how can I ensure that I don't run into this timeout issue?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help and pointers.  I think I've found the issue.  I had to increase the values of maxConcurrentCalls & maxConcurrentSessions - which in turn meant that the service had to have a InstanceContextMode of PerCall.

I was doing this earlier as well but in my load test was testing a unit test and those config changes were not making any difference.  When I created a new web test and then load tested that, everything seems to be hanging well together.  Haven't been able to figured out why that was the case though!

Answer (score 0):

OK, you say WCF and that is not enough. What binding are you using and where are you hosting it? If you are using IIS, the could be different underlying problem than self-hosting.

The likely reason is the small number of ThreadPool size. You can use `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads()` to change this but beware this is a sensitive value. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx).

Comment: Sorry - the service is being hosted in IIS and it's using basicHttpBinding. I'll try out the ThreadPool size suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following link:
http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2008/03/23/wcf-configuration-default-limits-concurrency-and-scalability.aspx

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Since the WCF service is doing a time consuming operation, you can't overload it and expect it to function. You can do the following (check the link about to set the following):

1. Increase the receiving capacity of the wcf service
2. Increase the send timeout of the service
3. Increase the send timeout of the client
4. Increase the receive timeout of the client
5. Limit the outgoing connections to the wcf service

**The best and most robust option would be to configure and use MSMQ with the WCF service.**

Comment: The service needs to be synchronous - so don't think MSMQ is an option - is it?  I haven't looked into MSMQ side of things.  I'll investigate that.  On your suggestions: how do I "Limit the outgoing connections to the wcf service"?

Comment: Try setting maxConnections (I think this includes both incoming and outgoing connections). Also checkout the TcpConnectionPoolSettings.MaxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint  property if you're using TCP or NamedPipes.

Comment: See if this helps: http://weblogs.asp.net/jclarknet/archive/2007/06/21/a-lesson-learned-about-concurrent-calls-and-wcf-binding-config.aspx